# XPath select an attribute based on value

Tags: vb.net, select, xpath, attributes, conditional-statements

Using VB.Net,

I have an XmlNode object, xNode.

I need to select an attribute of this node if it has a particular value.

e.g. `xNode.SelectSingleNode(".[@attr1='1']")`

I would expect this statement to return the attribute "attr1", only if it has a value of "1". However, I get an error - Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

When I tried this - `xNode.SelectSingleNode("@attr1[@attr1='1']")`
It always returns Nothing, even if the attribute has a value of 1.

I have tried a lot of different things, but no luck yet.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`//*[@attr1='1']/@attr1`

should do the trick.

Comment: I'm sorry to say it doesn't :(
No errors. Always returns nothing.